# What is the error in JQuery function

Tags: jquery

I want to get weather via API from yahoo . function fires until `html` .
I put `alert` before html in function . when it is before `html` it shows alert to me.
but when it is after `html` it does not work. it shows `html` has error. what is the issue ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.simpleWeather({
            zipcode: '',
            woeid: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.zipcode)',
            location: '',
            unit: 'c',
            success: function (weather) {
                //html = '<h2>' + weather.city + ', ' + weather.region + '</h2>';
                //html += '<img style="float:left;" width="125px" src="' + weather.image + '">';
                alert("hi");
                html += '<p>' + weather.temp + '&deg; ' + weather.units.temp + '<br /><span>' + weather.currently + '</span></p>';
                html += '<a href="' + weather.link + '">View Forecast &raquo;</a>';

                $("#weather").html(html);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $("#weather").html('<p>' + error + '</p>');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

now alert works

but in this alert does not works :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.simpleWeather({
            zipcode: '',
            woeid: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.zipcode)',
            location: '',
            unit: 'c',
            success: function (weather) {
                html = '<h2>' + weather.city + ', ' + weather.region + '</h2>';
                html += '<img style="float:left;" width="125px" src="' + weather.image + '">';
                alert("hi");
                html += '<p>' + weather.temp + '&deg; ' + weather.units.temp + '<br /><span>' + weather.currently + '</span></p>';
                html += '<a href="' + weather.link + '">View Forecast &raquo;</a>';

                $("#weather").html(html);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $("#weather").html('<p>' + error + '</p>');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is my html code :

```
<div id="weather"></div>
```

`html` has error . help me please .

Comment: Have you tried using F12 to see the error message on the developer tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't initialize nor declare `html` so this line can't append to it :

```
   html += '<p>' + weather.temp + '&deg; ' + ...
```

You could change `html +=` to `var html =`.

Note that the second code, even if it "works", still doesn't declare explicitly the html variable (the `var` keyword is missing) which makes it global.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the var html, e.g `var html = 'blah blah blah'`

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing a zipcode to the simpleWeather plugin.

`zipcode: '',`

You have to pass a zip code value. Example `zipcode: '90210',`

The code would be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.simpleWeather({
            zipcode: '90210',
            woeid: '@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.zipcode)',
            location: '',
            unit: 'c',
            success: function (weather) {
                html = '<h2>' + weather.city + ', ' + weather.region + '</h2>';
                html += '<img style="float:left;" width="125px" src="' + weather.image + '">';
                alert("hi");
                html += '<p>' + weather.temp + '&deg; ' + weather.units.temp + '<br /><span>' + weather.currently + '</span></p>';
                html += '<a href="' + weather.link + '">View Forecast &raquo;</a>';

                $("#weather").html(html);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $("#weather").html('<p>' + error + '</p>');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What about trying our easy [weather API](http://metwit.com/weather-api/)?

Here is a little **jQuery weather example**: 
http://jsbin.com/isukam/1

Let me know if you need help.

Disclosure: I own this API.